# subsequences and convergence for real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show there is a sequence $a_n$ such that for every real number x, there is a subsequence of $a_n$ converging to x. I have a hint that is to start with a bijection a:$\Bbb N$ $\to$ $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: The way I would approach this problem depends heavily on how a "real number" is defined already in the course/text.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a bijection $\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$: $f(n)$, and define $a_n = f(n)$.

Now let $x\in \Bbb R$. There is a sequence of rationals $(q^{(x)}_n)$ such as
$$
q^{(x)}_n\uparrow x
$$

Define $b_1 = q_1^{(x)}$ and, for every $n$ take $b_{n+1} \in \{q_k^{(x)}: k > n \}
\cap \{ f(k): k > n \}
$. This way, the sequence $(b_n)$ is extracted from $(a_n)$. And as $\liminf q_n^{(x)} 
= x$, you also have $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = x$.

Answer (score 0):

A different idea, for a more explicit example: $$a_{2^n+k}=2^{-n}\,(2k-2^n)\, n\qquad 0\leqslant k\leqslant2^n-1$$